# Type dynamic object functions call

Tags: typescript

I have this code ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=2#code/MYewdgzgLgBATiArlAphGBeGBvAsAKBiJgAcEArFYKCALhgApsBfASkwD4YAiAejJCVqEbgBoCxHgKE0AdCgAmASyjd6TGEoUxm9bJoX1ocJWADmO9hi4ADfhSo1eAEmxbmN8YWJwUJEHBQ6vrSjgCS2ro4pA7UEUZQJuaWnDB2vv6BLtihcQoeXswA3AQEUACeJCgwAEpIqOhYFVUgAGbw9Wgl+AQoAB6ZsK2IYNRK4DBmKGAocACGqACqcAA2ADwAcnMAttX9qGAK6ADWKOVttZ0QHAwSxGA7KPRbu16SJHPz23QwAAqfj1QcAgazqyDQAG0XigALocCEABhhBFYCSSFjw3iIoEgQzAmA64IgEIeuxh3UkvigiDg+NaYAYHy+EFY3WYQA)):

```
const routes = {
    projects: ({}) => "/projects",
    "projects.edit": ({ id }: { id: string }) => `/projects/${id}`,
    report: ({ projectId }: { projectId: string }) => `/report/${projectId}`,
};

type Routes = typeof routes;

export function generateUrl<Name extends keyof Routes>(
    name: Name,
    params: Parameters<Routes[Name]>[0]
): string {
    const fn = routes[name];
    return fn(params);
}
```

I get this error in line `fn(params)`. How would I write it to type-check (without using `any`)?

> Property 'id' is missing in type '{ projectId: string; }' but required in type '{ id: string; }'.

Comment: Hi, @jcalz, it seems a quite generic scenario, what do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another solution
This allows you to have routes that take multiple parameters.

```
type Route = (...args: any[]) => string;
type Routes = {
    [index: string]: Route;
};

function createUrlGenerator<T extends Routes>(router: T) {
    return <K extends keyof T>(name: K, ...params: Parameters<T[K]>): string => {
        return router[name].apply(null, params);
    }
}

const routes = {
    projects: ({}) => "/projects",
    "projects.edit": ({ id }: { id: string }) => `/projects/${id}`,
    report: ({ projectId }: { projectId: string }) => `/report/${projectId}`,
    multyParams: (id: number, query: string) => `${id}/${query}`
};

export const generateUrl = createUrlGenerator(routes);

generateUrl('multyParams', 123, '43');
generateUrl('multyParams', 123); // Exception
generateUrl('projects.edit', { id: '123' });
generateUrl('projects.edit', { id: 123 }); // Exception
```

Comment: Thx, I still get an error though, with both apply and call: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=15&ssc=2&pln=9&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBATiArlAphGBeGBvAsAKBiJgAcEArFYKCALhgApsBfASkwD4YAiAejJCVqEbgBoCxHgKE0AdCgAmASyjd6TGEoUxm9bJoX1ocJWADmO9hi4ADfhSo1eAEmxbmN8YWJwUJEHBQ6vrSjgCS2ro4pA7UEUZQJuaWnDB2vv6BLtihcQoeXswA3AQEUACeJCgwAEpIqOhYFVUgAGbw9Wgl+AQoAB6ZsK2IYNRK4DBmKGAocACGqACqcAA2ADwAcnMAttX9qGAK6ADWKOVttZ0QHAwSxGA7KPRbu16SJHPz23QwAAqfj1QcAgazqyDQAG0XigALocCEABhhBFYCSSFjw3iIoEgQzA9DBDShjxhmA64IgEIeuxh3UkvigiDgYBgrTAsmAcxWKwYYEQ3NEpAB31Y3WYQA

Comment: Edited my answer. The previous one worked only with strictBindCallApply = false

Answer (score 0):

```
const routes = {
    projects: ({}) => "/projects",
    "projects.edit": ({ id }: { id: string }) => `/projects/${id}`,
    report: ({ projectId }: { projectId: string }) => `/report/${projectId}`,
};

type Routes = typeof routes;

export function generateUrl<Name extends keyof Routes>(
    name: Name,
    params: Parameters<Routes[Name]>[0]
): string {
    const fn = routes[name] as ((p: typeof params => ReturnType<Routes[Name]>);
    return fn(params);
}
```

See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=16&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBATiArlAphGBeGBvAsAKBiJgAcEArFYKCALhgApsBfASkwD4YAiAejJCVqEbgBoCxHgKE0AdCgAmASyjd6TGEoUxm9bJoX1ocJWADmO9hi4ADfhSo1eAEmxbmN8YWJwUJEHBQ6vrSjgCS2ro4pA7UEUZQJuaWnDB2vv6BLtihcQoeXswA3AQEUACeJCgwAEpIqOhYFVUgAGbw9Wgl+AQoAB6ZsK2IYNRK4DBmKGAocACGqACqcAA2ADwAcnMAttX9qGAK6ADWKOVttZ0QHAwSxGA7KPRbu16SJHPz23QwAAqfj1QcAgazqyDQAG0XigALocCEABhhBFYCSSFjw3iIoEgQzAmA64IgEIeuxhMDm6AYDBI9GaKAuHy+ECsXBqKCgiDgYAAKpUUKCrlDHnDWN1JL5OdyYK0wDSAd8xQRmKV8FMZvMlqsGAByXI0HWiHBsAjq2YLFDLFa6-UQeTKKCG6Jaeg61ogEAAI0+Osspum5q11p1GQCjqNIViUHiMB13rg3oAXr6TfggA).

Basically the thing is that when retrieving the function from `routes`, TS wants to be extremely safe and forces the retrieved value to be called with the intersection of all possible parameter types, or `{} & {id: string} & {projectId: string}` in this case, which translates to `{id: string, projectId: string}`.

This is obviously not desired here, so we use a type-safe<sup>1</sup> cast.

Note however that there is one drawback. The presence of the `'projects'` route without any parameter makes the following line okay:

```
fn(42)
```

Should this be a problem, removing the bare route would solve it.

---

1: Try replacing `typeof params` with `number`.

Comment: Wow, funny stuff happens when making `projects` a parameter-less function. This makes me unsure of whether this is the best solution.